# angular material mat table multitemplatedatarows

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

[I want to make mat-table like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kn9F.png)

if you see the pic there is two lines with single value

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This not enough context @Mohamed. Provide code and well format it if you want people to help you